# Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, mobile, service

I have 3 tables (A - AB - B) which created by using Code-First "Azure Mobile Service"
Two tables (A and B) created with a model in the Mobile Service and the third table (AB) was created by the framework wich connect both tables as N:N relation the problem is when I create a new instance of A have a reference the other table B, the "InsertAsync(item);" tries to insert new instance in the other table which cause Conflict error because the entity is already exists, What I want is to insert into the relation table only (AB). My current solution is manually executing sql command with sql-string which as I think not a good solution. Is there any way that the framework can be informed that if the object exist just insert into the relation table. Thanks forall help.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the new Tag class:

```html
public class Tag 
    { 
        public int TagId{ get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
    }
```

And here is the new property added to the Post class:

```html
public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

you need to define in OnModelCreating in dbContext

```html
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>() 
                .HasMany(p => p.Tags) 
                .WithMany(t => t.Posts) 
                .Map(mc => 
                   { 
                       mc.ToTable("PostJoinTag"); 
                       mc.MapLeftKey("PostId"); 
                       mc.MapRightKey("TagId"); 
                   });
```

When you insert an A with list of B and B exist in the database, you need to add the

```html
 newA.ListOfB.Add(YourBFromDB)
```

where YourBFromDB is the object in your table. This way, you have 2 solutions:

- send to backend the right B
- in backend you will get the B based in the id sent by the app